# Is there a way to implement an array of LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linkedhashmap

I am trying to implement an array of LinkedHashMap but I don't know if it's possible...

For the moment my code looks like as follows :

```
public class LHMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>[] map = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         map[i] = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
  }

  map[0].put("a", 0);
  System.out.println(map[0].get("a"));

 }
}
```

```
System.out.println(extracted(map)[0].get("a"));
```

returns a "NullPointerException"...

Have you got any idea how to implement this?

EDIT : 1. erase extracted(), 2. table->array

Comment: What do you mean with "to do a table"?

Comment: What is the point of the `extracted()` method?

Comment: @BalusC: I think the OP means "use an array of..."

Comment: @BalusC : it's not table but array.

Comment: Couldn't you just use System.out.println in that for loop? If you really want to make a table I suggest that instead of extracted being a map you make it into a String[][]

Comment: @Matt Ball : In fact extracted() is useless...

Comment: `extracted` isn't doing anything. It's simply returning the parameter that is passed in. It's also the cause of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Why not just using an ArrayList containing LinkedHashMaps? Mixing Collections and Arrays is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your `extracted()` method is trying to do. You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you're passing `map` into `extracted` and then you're returning it immediately. In your example, you're passing in `null` and then returning it. You can't find the i<sup>th</sup> subscript (or any subscript) on a null array.

Instead of an array of `LinkedHashMap`, would a `List` work?

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   listOfMaps.add(new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>());
}

listOfMaps.get(0).put("a", 0);
System.out.println(listOfMaps.get(0).get("a"));
```

**EDIT**

You cannot instantiate an array with generics, by the way. I'd suggest going with the list if you want the type-safety. Otherwise you'd have to make do with:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>[] map = new LinkedHashMap[5];
```

This will give you warnings, however.

Comment: This solution works perfectly but isn't it "ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> listOfMaps" instead of "List<Map<String, Integer>> listOfMaps"?

Comment: Michaël, it is preferable to type an object with the interface instead of the concrete implementation (you're not tied to a specific implementation that way - gives you the advantage of loose coupling). `List` and `Map` are interfaces. Check out this link for more details: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html Also found this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered

Comment: Thank you for the links, the answer and comments. I understand, now, why I have to implement List but Eclipse returns an error with your implementation : "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parametrized with arguments <Map<String,Integer>>".

Comment: That shouldn't happen; not if you're using `java.util.List`. I tested out the code and it compiles.

Comment: My fault... I imported "java.awt.List" Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
map[i] = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

That will cause an NPE because you never initialize map, or rather, you explicitly initialize it to NULL:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>[] map = null;
```

EDIT:

You need to instantiate the array, e.g.:

```
map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>[]) new LinkedHashMap[5];
```

Although you'll get an "unchecked conversion" warning with that code. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation) for the generic array creation issue (thanks for those who pointed it out).

Comment: I am using Eclipse and it returns an error when I instantiate the array : "Cannot create a generic array of LinkedHashMapy<String,Integer>"

Comment: -1 This code will not compile. You cannot instantiate an array with generics. You'll get a compile-time error `generic array creation`.

Comment: How did this get voted up? This answer is **wrong**. You **cannot** instantiate an array with generics.