# Add an linkedhashmap to an Array

Tags: java, spring

I'm new with java and I have this doubt. I'm making a custom response in a Rest API and I want to introduce an array of errors with this format.

```
"http_code": 500,
"status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"info": "Internal Server Error",
"errors": [
      {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
      }
    ]
```

But I don't know how to do it on JAVA. My code until now it's something like this:

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, Object> arrayObj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
 arrayObj.put("code", 500);
 arrayObj.put("message", "Internal Server Error");

 List<> errors = new ArrayList<>(); //This part is where I don't know what to do
// Should I put a LinkedHashMap as output result?


LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("http_code", 500);
map.put("status", "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR");
map.put("info", "Internal Server Error");
map.put("errors", errors); // in this part would introduce the array of objects
```

I am not able to know how to do it, because if I put Linkedhasmap as a result, there is no method that returns the object as I want. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2:**

Finally, I resolved the puzzle. Here's the code:

```
 JSONArray errorArray = new JSONArray();
 JSONObject errorsObject= new JSONObject();
 errorsObject.put("code", 500);
 errorsObject.put("message", "Internal Server Error");
 errorArray.put(errorsObject.toMap());

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

 map.put("http_code", 500);
 map.put("status", "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"));
 map.put("info", info);
 map.put("errors", errorArray.toList());
```

Comment: You need to use a library like GSON to convert your data to json.

Comment: Why don't you define your error object ? Then use a parsing / serializing library of json like GSON or Jackson

Comment: Any example? and how would you do it? I'm a bit lost

Comment: very [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) to [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377754/parse-json-file-using-gson)

Comment: @JS4 there are plenty of examples out there. This site is not for suggestions but for solving well defined problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to implement an array of LinkedHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128923/is-there-a-way-to-implement-an-array-of-linkedhashmap)

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs but those examples gave me a string always with this format "[{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"error\"}]". Maybe I'm doing something wrong? what i need is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON shows a list of `error` objects, each with a `code` field and a `message` field.

You should serialise your data into a `List` of these objects and then place this into your `arrayObj`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/**

```
try
    {
        JSONObject customResponse=new JSONObject();
        JSONArray errorArray=new JSONArray();
        customResponse.put("errors", errorArray);
        JSONObject errorsObject=new JSONObject();
        errorsObject.put("code", "500");
        errorsObject.put("message", "Internal Server Error");
        errorArray.put(errorsObject);

        //customResponse will have format.....


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your code was very useful. You can see the solution in the new edit.

Comment: @JS4 I hope your doubt is solved, if you like my solution please up vote it.

Comment: I can't because I don't have 15 points of reputation yet. I will as soon as I have the rep.

Comment: Thanks in advance@JS4

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to describe it, which depend on requirement.

In usual cases error code should be one with multiple (similar type)messages.

**For Example** :- Request body contains multiple invalid values. In this scenario response will have code as **400** while message will be for **respective field(s)**.

You may return Object as shown below and build it as needed.

```
public class ErrorBuilder{
  private int errorCode;
  private List<String> errorMessages;
}
```