# what is the difference between these 2 lines?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the interface for a Java class be prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered)

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();


List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

what is the difference between these 2 lines?  Is there any rules that I should use former one rather than later one in any case? Or vise versa? What is advantage or disadvantage of using particular one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line creates an `ArrayList` and stores it in a variable of type of `ArrayList`, the second line stores it in a variable of type `List`.

`List` is an interface of which `ArrayList` is an implementation.  The rule of thumb for deciding which type to store the instance in (`List` or a specific implementation, like `ArrayList`) is that you should store at the most generalized level suitable for your needs. This means that if you know that the variable must conform to behavior only exhibited by `ArrayList` and not a `List` in general, then you should use `ArrayList`, otherwise, use `List`. (This holds for `LinkedList` or other `List` implementations, too)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you want to use the second line it's because it's usually better to program to interfaces than to classes, sometimes it's related to good practices to do that and one of the benefits it's that you end up with code that:

It's better to test
Can use different implementations
It's not coupled to ArrayList

For more information you can take a look at the "Hollywood principle" or the Strategy pattern