# Adding items to Array List with specified objects

Tags: android, arraylist

I am working in a translator kind of app and i need some help.
I have a class with getters and setters for my Array List objects. Each object has a phrase, a meaning, and usage.

so i have this to create my list:

```
ArrayList<PhraseCollection> IdiomsList = new ArrayList<PhraseCollection>();
```

now how do i add these objects to the list, each object containing the phrase, its meaning, and a use in a sentence?

For Example: The Layout would be something like this

### Phrase

Kick the bucket

### Meaning

When someone dies

### Usage

My grandfather kicked the bucket

#### Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

this is what i came up with that worked for me

```
private void loadIdioms() {

    //creating new items in the list
    Idiom i1 = new Idiom();
    i1.setPhrase("Kick the bucket");
    i1.setMeaning("When someone dies");
    i1.setUsage("My old dog kicked the bucket");
    idiomsList.add(i1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) has a method call add() or add(ELEMENT,INDEX);
In order to add your objects you must first create them

```
PhraseCollection collection=new PhraseCollection();
```

then create the ArrayList by

```
ArrayList<PhraseCollection> list=new ArrayList<PhraseCollection>();
```

add them by :

```
list.add(collection);
```

Last if you want to render that in your ListView item, you must override the toString() in your PhraseCollection.

Comment: but how do i add the specific fields to my object

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would use the add(E) method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)).

Here is an example using your example provided.

```
public class Phrase {
    public final String phrase, meaning, usage;
    //TODO: implement getters?

    public Phrase(String phrase, meaning, usage) {
        this.phrase = phrase;
        this.meaning = meaning;
        this.usage = usage;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
// create the list
ArrayList<Phrase> idiomsList = new ArrayList<Phrase>();

// create the phrase to add
Phrase kick = new Phrase("kick the bucket", "When someone dies", "My grandfather kicked the bucket");

// add the phrase to the list
idiomsList.add(kick);
```

Comment: Generally prefer List<X> mylist = new ArrayList<X>();  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n

Comment: how do you retrieve say the meaning?

Comment: you could use: `kick.meaning`