# pass ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to another activity

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> HoldAllData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

can i send HoldAllData to another activity using `putStringArrayListExtra`? i know how to send `ArrayList<String>` to another activity but this is a list of string list. HoldAllData is filled by database read values and is a n-row by 5-columns list of strings.

Comment: Should be `List<List<String>> HoldAllData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Comment: no it shouldn't because it is working and holds all database values

Comment: Of course it works, but that doesn't make it the right practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered

Comment: u r wrong, ur code give me error. the correct implementation is: List<ArrayList<String>> HoldAllDatar = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Comment: You ARE right and wrong at the same time, it should be `List<List<String>> HoldAllData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();` sorry about the initial error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can achieve the same by setting data in the bundle through `.putSerializable("key", HoldAllData );` then later to retrieve the list in other activity cast the serializable data `Object o = bundle.getSerializable("key"); if o instanceof ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> holdAllData = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>)o;`

Comment: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Serializable to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: it returns null value for HoldAllData in the second activity

Comment: what is the key name you are giving ?Make sure  HoldAllData  in the first activity is not null.

Comment: it is not, it has all row which i want. the key name is set to "mykey" in both activities

Comment: serializable is not good for android performance wise use parceable

Comment: @HosseinAmini are you setting the bundle in the intent? show your code please.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(ReportsDialog.this, ReportsActivity.class);    
    Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
    mybundle.putSerializable("mykey", HoldAllData );
    intent.putExtras(mybundle);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: @IllegalArgument yes parceable is better in terms of performance.

Comment: @HosseinAmini how are you retrieving in the ReportsActivity?

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> HoldAllData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();      
  HoldAllData = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) bundle.getSerializable("mykey");

Comment: You are creating a new bundle, it will not contain anything. Fetch from the bundle send by previous activity. Change the first line `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();` to `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();`