# What is the Advantage of creating ArrayList in java by the below mentioned way

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I am new to Java. What is the advantage or difference of creating `ArrayList` by:
`List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>;`
over
`ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: In the first case, `a` can accept an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList` etc provided that it is a `List`

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2071828

Comment: Note that this is not done only specific to ArrayList or List.

Answer (score 1):

You're decoupling your code from a specific implementation of an interface, see this answer for more detail:
[Polymorphism: Why use "List list = new ArrayList" instead of "ArrayList list = new ArrayList"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n)