# what is the difference and similarity between creating object in this 2 ways?

Tags: java

I have a confusion please help

```
class Animal {
   public void move() {
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
         public void move() {
            System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
         }
}

public class TestDog {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     Animal a = new Animal();   // Animal reference and object
     **Animal b = new Dog();   // Animal reference but Dog object**

     a.move();   // runs the method in Animal class
     b.move();   // runs the method in Dog class
    }
 }
```

while creating Animal reference but Dog object we could have done

```
Dog b = new Dog();
```

and we would have the same result,
so i just wanted to know whats the difference and when do we use it?

Comment: Similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n

Comment: its not clear, my code is not using interface at all.

Comment: "To program an interface" also applies to regular inheritance (The Animal class). The link I provided gives your answer "it allows you to switch between different implementations of the [Animal class] with ease." For example, A wolf could extend a dog, a wolf is still an animal, and you can easily switch out the implementation. It's more clear which you use if you defined a bark method on the dog class, but not the animal class

Comment: @cricket_007 i understand now. thanks