# List versus ArrayList

Tags: java, inheritance, run-time-polymorphism

Which one is better and why ?

a) `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

b) `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: a) List list = new ArrayList<>();  is the best. In future if you want to change ArrayList to LinkedList, it requires only minimum code change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n

Comment: option a) better way to initialize list,

Comment: You could also use Collection<String> myStringCollection = new Arraylist<>(); This will allow your Methods to accept more than just objects which are instances of ArrayList. You could also then pass Set's. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Define _better_

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

If you care only about the list semantics and not for the particular implementation, go for `List<String>`. If you want to enforce a particular implementation, go for `ArrayList<String>`, `LinkedList<String>` or anything else.

In most cases, you will want to go on with the interface and not the particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

(a) is better because it is more flexible. If for example, suddenly your requirement changes and says "Instead of creating a new empty array list to assign to the variable `list`, we will populate the `list` with items filtered from another list", you need to change your code for that. You might change it to something like this:

```
List<String> list = anotherList.stream().filter(x -> x.length() > 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since `collect(Collectors.toList())` returns a `List`, you also need to change the type of `list` if you were using the code in (b).

Another situation is that later on you found out that you need to assign some other kind of list e.g. `LinkedList` to `list`. If you were using the code in (a), you can just assign the linked list straight away. If you were using the code in (b), you will have to go back to the declaration of `list` and change the type.

The general pattern is that as you use more "abstract" types, your code becomes more flexible but at the same time you can do less with your variables. For example, you can't use methods declared only in `ArrayList` on your `list` variable, but on the other hand, other kinds of lists can be assigned to `list`. If you an even more abstract type, `Collection`, then you can't use the members only declared in `List` anymore, but then all kinds of collections - `Set`, `Map` etc - can be assigned.