# Java new Integer() is blocked

Tags: java

I create Vector and I want add Integer in vector.
but "new Integer()" have error.

```
Vector<Integer> intergers = new Vector<Integer>();
intergers.add(new Integer());
```

what can i do?

- now i use "Integer" & parameter like "new Integer(0)"
  but "new Integer(0)" have yellow underline. what can i do to remove this line?
- ok, why The constructor Integer(int) is deprecated since version 9?
- ok! i found why.

"It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory valueOf(int) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

thx all

Comment: You wrote Interger?

Comment: yes? but it make error.

Comment: Because it's Integer not Interger.

Answer (score 4):

You should use "Integer", not "Interger". Moreover, Integer class does not accept an empty constructor. The working code should be:

```
Vector<Integer> integers = new Vector<Integer>();
integers.add(new Integer(2));
```

However, Java has the [Auto boxing/unboxing](https://www.javatpoint.com/autoboxing-and-unboxing) concept. So the more concise code will be:

```
Vector<Integer> integers = new Vector<Integer>();
integers.add(2);
```

Vector's methods are synchronized so it supports multiple threading. However, it is not good in most situations. So I recommend you switch to ArrayList. So the updated version is:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(2);
```

And the final point, you should prefer using `List as the datatype because of [Program to interfaces, not implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean) [List vs ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n). So the final version should be:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) doesn't have a no-arguments constructor.

The only constructors are the ones that take a `String` or an `int` respectively.

So you can do:

```
integers.add(new Integer("6"));
```

or

```
integers.add(new Integer(5));
```

The later one is deprecated though and should be replaced with `Integer.valueOf(5)`.

Comment: Note that `Integer​(int value)` is deprecated since Java 9. It's better to use `Integer.valueOf(5)` instead.

Comment: `integers.add(5);` is easier again.

Answer (score 1):

You should have written `Integer` and pass it a parameter as follows:

```
Vector<Integer> intergers = new Vector<Integer>();
intergers.add(new Integer(1));
```

Comment: thx but it have yellow line

Comment: I edited the answer to contain the two lines and tested them on my computer.

Comment: @MajedBadawi - you should avoid using `new Integer(1)` as this constructor has been deprecated. You should use `Integer.valueOf(1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) does not have a no-arg constructor. Even the one-arg constructor is deprecated and you should avoid using that. You should use `Integer.valueOf(int)` instead e.g.

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

However, you can simply do as follows:

```
Vector<Integer> intergers = new Vector<Integer>();
intergers.add(0);
```

and [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) feature of Java will make sure that `0` is converted to `Integer.valueOf(0)` automatically.