# What's are the difference between these two implementations

Tags: java, generic-list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Which one is preferable? and why?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10999280/3572733

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Arraylist**, it will be for arraylist only. however if you use **List** it can be also used for **Linkedlist**. Also if you use list, the other function of arraylist will be shadowed.

I preferred the **List** Implementation when function only using to add,remove and get values on the **ArrayList**.