# Why is it a poor style to expose the implementation of a set in Java

Tags: java, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the interface for a Java class be prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered)

I read in a book that It’s poor style to expose the implementation, so:

Good: `Set s = new HashSet( );`

Fair: `HashSet s = new HashSet( );`

can you explain why this is?

Answer (score 0):

You should always program to an interface and not to an implementation. This allows loose coupling.
For instance if you replace `HashSet` to a `TreeSet` in the first case your code will not be affected. Compare such a change with the second case.
So you would be able to switch implementations without affecting client code as long as client code uses the interface instead of the concrete type.