# Using interfaces over classes

Tags: java, interface, coupling

I'm a bit confused about the advice to use the Interface for a Java class, like in this thread: [Why should the interface for a Java class be preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered)

I understand why you would want to use the interface: if something changes later you have less code to clean up.

But aren't there cases in which using the Interface would prevent you from being able to take advantage of the performance reason why you chose that particular class in the first place?

For instance, if I have a TreeMap, I assume that I should be able to locate any element in at most O(logn). That's why it has nice methods I can take advantage of like higherEntry(), lowerEntry(), lastEntry().

If I instead reference this TreeMap as a Map, now I believe I am forced to iterate one element at a time through my list in O(n) to locate that entry.

I'm new to Java, so let me know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

> If I instead reference this TreeMap as a Map, now I believe I am
>   forced to iterate one element at a time through my list in O(n) to
>   locate that entry.

No you are not forced to do that. If you are sure that your `Map` reference is holding a reference to `TreeMap`, and you want to access specific method of `TreeMap`, then you can always typecast the `Map` reference to a `TreeMap` reference, and then access the appropriate method, like, `higherEntry()`, `lowerEntry()`. 
But, the only caveat is that, you have to be sure that your `Map` reference is actually pointing to a `TreeMap`, to avoid getting a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

This is implied by the fact that, a `super class` and it's `sub classes` are *covariant* in nature. So, you can perform cast between them, provided you are not breaking the rules at runtime (That is having the `super class` reference holding the reference to some other `sub class` instance, which is not covariant with the `sub class` you are casting to).

Now for your example, since the [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) also implements the [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface, which is a sub interface of `Map` interface, so you can use it instead of `Map` interface. So, you can have the advantage of polymorphism, without the need to typecast.

Comment: I see. Yeah, the NavigableMap does provide all of that functionality. So, perhaps for any case I could imagine like this a Subinterface exists?

Comment: @vmayer.. Well, you can't infer a particular design for all cases looking jsut at one case. It is not hard and fast, that you might have multiple interfaces convering all the methods of your class. But in maximum cases, yeah that should be true.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use methods like `higherEntry`, `lowerEntry`, and `lastEntry`, then just use the `NavigableMap` interface instead of the `Map` interface or the `TreeMap` class.

In general, use interfaces as often as possible, and use the most general interface you can that supports all the operations you'd want to use.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question. He used that as an example, not a problem he has.

Comment: No, I think it does answer the question. NavigableMap seems to take care of both the design goal of using an Interface and the performance issue.