# passing an object to function

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making something but I can't seem to make it work. I get a nullpointerexception, but I can't figure out why.

```
public class Bus implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<Reiziger> reizigers;

    public String add(Reiziger reiziger) {
        reizigers.add(reiziger);
        return "lijst";
    }
}
```

The nullpointer happens at line "`reizigers.add(reiziger);`" in the add method of `Bus.java`

Comment: is bus null or reiziger?

Comment: reiziger gets filled up in the view. <h:inputText id="naam" value="#{reiziger.naam}" label="naam" required="true" requiredMessage="  Naam invullen is required."/>

Comment: Hi, greetings from Utrecht... for future questions, please try to write a title that is abput the 'root-cause'  of the problem. The NPE is the cause, where it happens is very relevant. The title of this question is totally unrelated to the problem but just a statement of you want to achieve. If you have a root cause it is easier to find similar questions.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: And btw, you do not need to pass the reiziger as a parameter. It nost likely is available in the scope already (but it does work and is not 'wrong' ) but in general it looks like your 'model' is to tightly coupled to the ui now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `ArrayList<Reiziger> reizigers` before use it:

```
List<Reiziger> reizigers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, note that `List` interface type is used for `reizigers` collections instead of `ArrayList` implementation. Read [here the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-preferred)

Comment: NPE is usually an easy fix =)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will probably not forget this again :) Also thanks for the link with info!

Comment: Accepting the answer is the best gratitude =)

Comment: accept the answer by the checkmark if it worked for you!!! ;)