# Why up-casting to Webdriver is done instead of RemoteWebdriver while working with any browser driver in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, upcasting

RemoteWebdriver implements Webdriver interface then why don't we up-cast to RemoteWebdriver instead of Webdriver while creating object of any browser driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition upcasting is

> a variable of Parent class refers to the object of Child class

In other words if `class A` is parent, then `class B extends A` is a child. Upcasting would be:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b; // upcasting
```

But relationship between RemoteWebDriver and WebDriver is not of a parent/child:

```
RemoteWebDriver implements WebDriver
```

Hence there's no upcasting here. And the question is different:

> why don't we *declare concrete type* RemoteWebDriver instead of WebDriver while creating object of any browser driver

the reasons are same as when answering a more generic question: [Why should the interface for a Java class be preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-preferred). And really: if Selenium developers removed/deprecated `RemoteWebDriver` would you want to change your tests?

BTW: here's a case of actual upcasting *to* RemoteWebDriver:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // ChromeDriver extends RemoteWebDriver
RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = driver;
```

Also the following is valid, although hard to find a reason why you'd want to do it:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
```

One use case I've seen is when people want to use some other interface implemented by RemoteWebDriver (i.e. not `WebDriver`, but say `TakesScreenshot`). But then it's better to cast to that interface directly:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
ts.getScreenshotAs(...);
```