# How to convert this method to a boolean

Tags: java, arrays, list, chess

I'm currently trying to implement a game of chess. I've structured it so that possible moves are generated for each piece type and stored in an array list. My board is a 2d array. I wondered how to write that if the xTo yTo(coordinates of spot wanted to move to) was a possible move then that move could be made, but it won't let me use the array `list.contains()`, any suggestions much appreciated! Here is an example of what I have. (The user enters the coordinates xFrom, yFrom then xTo yTo via the terminal)
I'm now wondering if it would be easier to convert this to a boolean? and getting rid of the array list?

```
public Board() {
    this.boardsize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

    board = new char[boardsize][boardsize];

    // Clear all playable fields
    for (int x = 0; x < boardsize; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < boardsize; y++)
            board[x][y] = FREE;

    board[0][7] = BLACKROOK;
    board[2][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
    board[5][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
    board[7][7] = BLACKROOK;
    board[0][0] = WHITEROOK;
    board[2][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
    board[5][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
    board[7][0] = WHITEROOK;
```

For the Rook....

```
public ArrayList<int[]> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<int[]>();


public ArrayList<int[]> generatePossibleMoves(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom) {
    for (int i = 1; xFrom + i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom + i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
            if (gameBoard[xFrom + i][yFrom] != FREE) {
                int[] move = {xFrom + i, yFrom};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
                break;                              //stops iterating here since a rook is not allowed to jump over other pieces
            } else
                {
                int[] move = {xFrom + i, yFrom};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; xFrom - i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom - i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
            if (gameBoard[xFrom - i][yFrom] != FREE) {
                int[] move = {xFrom - i, yFrom};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
                break;
            }
            else
                {
                int[] move = {xFrom - i, yFrom};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; yFrom + i < gameBoard.length+1; i++) {       //makes sure the place to be moved is on the board
        if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom + i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
            if (gameBoard[xFrom][yFrom+i] != FREE) {
                int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom+i};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
                break;
            }
            else
                {
                int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom+i};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; yFrom- i < gameBoard.length+1; i++)
        if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom - 1) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
            if (gameBoard[xFrom][yFrom - 1] != FREE) {
                int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom - 1};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
                break;
            } else {
                int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom - 1};
                possibleMoves.add(move);
            }
        }
    return possibleMoves;
}




public boolean moveLegal(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo){
    generatePossibleMoves(gameBoard, xFrom,yFrom);

    if(possibleMoves.contains(xTo,yTo){
        //this is where I'm stuck
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a new Point class with x,y variable and implement hashcode and equals method on this class. Then change possibleMoves to Set<Point>. That will solve you current problem. On the algo side, I would recommend doing the validation directly without generating all the possible moves.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 0):

To check if the move is possible, one way to do is to compare the couple { xTo, yTo } with all the legal moves you calculate through your generatePossibleMoves function :

```
public boolean moveLegal(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int 
yTo){
       int[] wantedMove = new int[] {xTo, yTo};
       ArrayList<int[]> possibleMoves = generatePossibleMoves(gameBoard, xFrom,yFrom);
       boolean isMoveLegal = possibleMoves.stream().anyMatch(possibleMove -> 
           Arrays.equals(wantedMove, possibleMove));
       return isMoveLegal;
}
```

Comment: this seems great! but it doesn't like -> Arrays.equals

Comment: You are probably using a lower version than Java 8. This should work on Java 8+.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another class Coordinates that implements correctly the equals method

```
public class Coordinates {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Coordinates other = (Coordinates) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

and then use this class for the type of ArrayList

So for example

```
public List<Coordinates> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
```

then the function becomes

```
public boolean moveLegal(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo){
    generatePossibleMoves(gameBoard, xFrom,yFrom);
    Coordinates checkCoordinates = new Coordinates (xTo,yTo);
    if(possibleMoves.contains(xTo,yTo){
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The best practice is to declare field type as generic as possivle. That's why I would suggest you to use `List` instead `ArrayList` and change `public ArrayList<Coordinates> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();` to `public List<Coordinates> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();`

Comment: Hi @ADS I absolutely agree. I have written a quick exam in order MuratK to see how he can use the contains method without changing too much his current code.

Comment: Sure, don't get my comment as personal attack. I'm here just to help you to improve your answer since it could see many people, not only the author.

Comment: I have up voted both of your comments and edited my code.thanks!

Comment: so would everything work if I just used list?(sorry I'm kinda new to programming

Comment: also, is this @over ride needed?

Comment: @Shemar Annotation `@Override` is not needed but it's much, much better to add it. It helps to avoid such silly mistakes like having `equals(Coordinates)` instead of `equals(Object)`. With `@Override` compiler would suggest that you have mistake.

Comment: @Shemar about `List` and `ArrayList` you could read more [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-preferred). In short, having `List` is just best-practice which helps when you when you change code (and you will do so even if not planning right now). But this change do not solve any problem: both options would compile.  Also, I would suggest to have a book for Java beginners. It answer to many questions even before you ask them.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you save in `possibleMoves` array but trying to check **not** an array. As described in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), `List.contains()` accepts only 1 parameter. Since you put array to your `List`, you could want to check against array: `if(possibleMoves.contains({xTo,yTo})`

But in fact it wouldn't work correctly. You mixed up possible moves from all pieces so you could select Queen and move to any point which could reach a Knight.

**Offtopic**:
I would suggest you to use more OOP-style approach: use less raw arrays and more objects which reflects pieces. For example

```
enum Side { 
   White; Black; 
   public Side opposite() {
      if (this==White) return Black;
      else return White;
   }
}
// in separate file
class Pawn {
  private ChessSquare currentPosition;
  private final Side color;
  public boolean couldMoveTo(ChessSquare another) {
     if (currentPosition.x == another.x) {
       return another.y - currentPosition.y == 1; //TODO check for first move in two sruares
     } else if (another.hasPiece(this.color.opposite())) {
        // TODO allow to take enemy piece in diagonal
     }
  }
 public List<ChessField> possibleMoves() { 
   List<ChessField> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for (currentSquare in ALL_SQUARES) {
     if (couldMoveTo(currentSquare)) result.add(currentSquare)
   }
   return result;
}
```

My example is inefficient and could be improved in many ways. Also there are many other options how to organize code structure. I suppose it demonstrated how you could check if a piece could make move **from perspective of this piece**. Also you could hide many details (like *en passant* rule) inside `Pawn` class and in the same time have clear code at upper levels. You could see that `possibleMoves()` is very small and in fact could be common for all pieces.

P.S. Chess is a great game and I wish you could learn both chess and Java while creating your game.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses, would it be easier to convert this method to a boolean? returning true if can move and false if not?

Comment: @Shemar I just forgot to declare return type for method `couldMoveTo`. I updates answer