# How to create a arraylist of multiple lists java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i have started coding again in java after a few years of break and im trying to refresh up a bit now, but i seem to be struggeling to create a list of lists, not a multidimensional for example i just dump all my lists in one variable, if i need list x i fetch list x and assign that to a variable for easy access rather then looping through second dimension variabel.

this is what i currently have:

```
package src.handlers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TextManager {
    public static void load_chapters(){
        ArrayList sections = new ArrayList();
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\0.intro.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\1.hello_world.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\2.comments.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\3.variabelen.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\4.operators.txt"));    

        for(int x=0; x < sections.size(); x++){
            // what i attempt to do ->
            Object current_section = sections.get(x); // This gives object conversion error when assigning as List<String>
            // loop here that loops all lines  in current section.
            // cannot access  cause get function says its an object not a list?
            System.out.println(current_section.get(3));
        }
    }


    public static List<String> read_lines(String filename){
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Probeer het bestand in  te lezen.
        try { // Maak buffereader aan voor het inlezen met filereader module.
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String cur_line;
            // zolang er een nieuwe lijn word gevonden en deze niet null is -> output toevoegen aan output variabel.
            while((cur_line = read.readLine()) != null){
                output.add(cur_line);
            } // Sluiten  van buffer reader voor exceptions te voorkomen / latere toegang mogelijk te maken.
            read.close();
            return output; //terugave vanalle file output.
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.format("Exeption occured trying to read from '%s'.", filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

got it thanks due alex :D

```
    public static void load_chapters(){
        ArrayList<List<String>> sections = new ArrayList();
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\0.intro.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\1.hello_world.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\2.comments.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\3.variabelen.txt"));
        sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\4.operators.txt"));    

        for(List<String> section : sections){
            for(String line : section){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Raw types are one problem here... The other one is the fact that you want to be able to easily fetch the lists, but if you store them in a `List<List<String>>`, you will have to know the index of the list in the parent list or you have to check its values. **Use a `Map<String, List<String>>` for this**...

Answer (score 1):

To create a list of lists, just initialize it as so:

```
List<List<String>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's advisable to avoid using the implementation types, like `ArrayList`; please **use interface** `List` instead. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147495/6908551) for that.

And then, you could just do:

```
sections.add(read_lines("src\\chapters\\0.intro.txt"));
// ... and so on
```

When iterating through the list, I recommend using the for-each loop:

```
for (List<String> section : sections) {
    System.out.println(section.get(3));
}
```

But, if you still want to use the index approach (although **not recommended** when iterating through Java lists), here's the code for that:

```
for (int x = 0; x < sections.size(); x++) {
    List<String> current_section = sections.get(x);
    System.out.println(current_section.get(3));
}
```

Not related to your question, but some **notes** on the [naming conventions](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-java-naming-conventions-2034199):

- variables and method names should be `mixedCase` (or `lowerCamelCase`)

  - the `current_section` variable should be renamed as `currentSection`
  - the `read_line` and `load_chapters` methods I would rename them as `readLine` and `loadChapters`.

Comment: Thankyou exactly what i wanted :D

Comment: Also: thanks for iteration tip, my java is  pretty rust didnt know you could iter that way much easier :) coded only 2-3 years and that was 10years+ ago when  info was still scarse.

Comment: Another offtopic: isnt mixed/camel case for classes ? i use as naming convention: _globalvar, normalvar, Class, function_name

Comment: For classes it's **upper** camel case, like `class MyClass`. Your class name `TextManager` is correct. Check the article I've posted. Usually that's the rule of thumb for naming in Java, but you could use what you like.

Answer (score 0):

1) The first thing that I would point out is that you are working with a raw `ArrayList`, since Java 1.5 we got Generics, so instead of working with casted Objects you can now work with objects from the class that you want, like you did in your `read_lines(String)` method

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
// etc.
for(int x=0; x < sections.size(); x++){
    ArrayList<String> current_section = sections.get(x);
    System.out.println(current_section.get(3));
}
```

2) Also it is a good practice to declare variable by their interfaces, instead of the concrete implementation, so the code above would be something like:

```
List<List<String>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
// Depending on your needs you could change your List<> implementation like:
// List<List<String>> sections = new LinkedList<>();
// List<List<String>> sections = new Vector<>();
// etc.
for(int x=0; x < sections.size(); x++){
    List<String> current_section = sections.get(x);
    System.out.println(current_section.get(3));
}
```

3) But if you decide to continue working with your current code (raw `ArrayList`) you should make a small change because you are trying to access a method available only on the `ArrayList` class. To accomplish what you want you would need to to a cast to get the value from your `current_section` object.

```
for(int x=0; x < sections.size(); x++){
    ArrayList current_section = (ArrayList)sections.get(x); // CAST
    System.out.println(current_section.get(3));
}
```